# MySQL: Add ID by Group value

Tags: mysql, grouping

Let's say I have a table `myTable` like this:

```
col1   | col 2
-------+---------
213    | Peach
32467  | Peach
44     | Apple
5      | Banana!
3      | Banana!
```

How can I add an `id` column to get a result like this:

```
col1   | col 2   | id
-------+---------+------
213    | Peach   | 1
32467  | Peach   | 1
44     | Apple   | 2
5      | Banana! | 3
3      | Banana! | 3
```

?

`col 2` can contain any value...

Comment: Considering that rows in SQL represent unordered sets, why is the result peach/apple/banana rather than banana/peach/apple, say

Answer (score 0):

Is there a better way than doing

```
SELECT `col 1`, `col 2`, groupID
FROM `myTable` as a, 
(SELECT `col 2`, @groupID := ifnull(@groupID,0) + 1 as groupID 
FROM myTable
GROUP by 1) as b
ON a.`col 2` = b.`col 2`
```

?

Comment: Yes, normalizing the schema (i.e. moving `col 2` to another table). Otherwise, no (check the syntax of the join though). Shouldn't this be an edit of your question instead of an answer though?

Comment: this query doesn't work, instead of giving you 1,2,3, it gives you 1,4,5, try it. this is because group by clause executed after the variables assigned in Select clause.

Answer (score 0):

First, you may use this query to assign an ID to each group:

```
SET @i = 0;
SELECT DISTINCT col2, (@i:= @i+1) as id FROM `myTable`
```

You will get something like:

```
| col2    | id |
+---------+----|
| Peach   | 1  |
| Apple   | 2  |
| Banana! | 3  |
```

Then you may JOIN this subquery to your table on 'col2':

```
SET @i = 0;
SELECT a.*, b.id from `myTable` as a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT col2, (@i:= @i+1) as id FROM `myTable`
) b ON a.col2 = b.col2
```

And you will get what you need. Of course, ifnull() function allows to avoid SET statement.

But, are you sure you need this `id` column? If you don't have it stored in the table, there is a little probability you need it at all.